# Methods similar to Request.Form for setting values instead of reading them?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, request

I'm experienced with using Request.Form["someName"] to pull the value held by a control, but am looking for a similar method that will allow me to set the value of a control.

The code would be a lot to copy paste, but here are a few reasons why I am needing this specific method.

1. Rows in a table are being copied and inserted into the HTML via JavaScript - this disables my ability to use "FindControl" to find the controls (I've already tried this)
2. I'm ultimately looking to do validation of these controls.  Imagine the following (VERY simplified example).

   ```
   <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox id="txt__1" runat="server" />
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvalTxt__1" />
         </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```

On a certain button click, the table row is copied and inserted below to create the following (via JavaScript, which is why I cannot explicitly set values)

```
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
             <asp:TextBox id="txt__1" runat="server" />
             <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvalTxt__1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             <asp:TextBox id="txt__2" runat="server" />
             <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvalTxt__2" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have a functional way to get the values of these controls in the codebehind (C#) using Request.Form and the container's UniqueID property, but need a way to set the custom validator based on the content of several other textboxes in this form.

Are there methods similar to Request.Form that I could use to set the value of a specific validator in this table to true from my C# code behind?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm thinking my best course of action might be to validate with JavaScript instead of in the code behind, adding some sort of class or something and making a foreach function that loops through and checks that way - but would still like to hear any other thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access a control and its contents and properties is by accessing the object that represents the control.  For example. instead of reading `Form[MyControl.UniqueID]` you should use `this.MyControl.Text`.  In a similar fashion you can set the contents, e.g. using `this.MyControl.Text = "Some value"`.

To set a validator's property, use

```
this.MyValidator.SomeProperty = someValue;
```

If the validator was created dynamically, you should be able to access it using the [Page.Validators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validators%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection.

Comment: I don't have the control. Since it's being added after the page has already loaded, it can't be found on the page via codebehind. That's the issue here.  My only way of accessing the control right now is to use Request.Form to access the value.

Comment: If the validator hasn't been added yet then I don't see how you could possibly expect to set any of its properties.  Perhaps you could inject some query into the page to set it after the page is rendered?

Comment: It's added at runtime, so I cannot set it explicity and furthermore the code behind does not recognize it when I use any sort of "find control" method. I'm thinking I'm going to have to validate with javascript.

Comment: If you have code that adds it at run time can't you set its properties the moment after you've instantiated it?

Comment: I don't have a way to access the control.  FindControl does not work in this case. The only way I can access it's value is through Request.Form["controlname"], but this is readonly and will not allow me to set it's value this way.

Comment: How about the [Page.Validators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validators%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection?